# How to log my process id using logging module

Tags: python, function, logging, process, pid

How to log my process my module using python. My script will get Pid and process.

I want to log the output

```
import psutil
[p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'firefox' in p.info['name']]
```

Output > [{'pid': 413, 'name': 'firefox'}]

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info()
```

Comment: You use `logging.info()` in the same way you would use `print()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import psutil
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
process_list = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'firefox' in p.info['name']]
for process in process_list:
    logging.info('process name %s' % process['name'])
```

Answer (score 23):

I think there is a simpler solution: the *logging* module can automatically display the Process ID.

```
FORMAT = '%(process)d %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
```

see docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes